# installing Win 7 from Vista

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I have Win Vista 32 bit system and I want to know if I can install Win 7 64 bit system without doing the so called "clean install". I know if I go from my 32 bit to Win 7 32 bit is a very seamless upgrade, but the change to 64 bit is confusing for me. Thanks!!

Comment: What processor do you have ? 32 or 64bits ? That would be a good start to decide that !

Comment: Fretje: thank you, I have a 32 bit processer, I do have 4g ram, but after reading all the answers, I am going to just upgrade to the 32 bit version as I am very happy with my system, no need to experiment at this point. 
Harry

Answer (score 4):

You cannot upgrade from a 32-bit installation to a 64-bit installation without doing a clean install.  This is probably due to the fact that things are organized slightly differently on the 64-bit version of Windows (it has two Program Files folders, etc.).  Here's a guide to the types of upgrades that can be done:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No.  If you upgrade, you will have to do a full format and install.

Check into Windows "Easy Transfer" to help ease the pain.

[This post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Windows7EasyUpgradePathTruthTableChart.aspx) by Scott Hanselman details more about the process and options.

Comment: Easy Transfer makes it a lot nicer.  All of your settings will transfer.  Unfortunately, you still need to reinstall all of the applications.

Comment: Yes, for sure requires the full format!

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to reformat to change OS from 32-bit to 64-bit. The differences in the Architecture make it so that an upgrade is really hard if not impossible.