# 64 bit to Windows 7 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, 64-bit, upgrade, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [installing Win 7 from Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/24728/installing-win-7-from-vista)

I have a AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual core processor on my computer with Vista Home Premium, but I believe it using a 32 bit Vista version(how can I find out what bit my system is really using?). Can I upgrade to Win 7 64 bit Home, if my present OS is using a 32 bit Vista OS.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? http://superuser.com/questions/24728/installing-win-7-from-vista

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upgrade a 32-bit OS to a 64-bit version; you have to do a clean install. Don't worry, though, all your old files will be moved to a new directory called `Windows.old`, so you won't lose anything, you'll just have to reinstall your applications.

To find out which version you have, go to Control Panel -> System and Maintenance -> System, and it should say either 32-bit or 64-bit Operating System.